# Why cannot connect remote report server instance?

Tags: sql-server, ssrs

I have a SQL Server reporting service on `ServerR`.

I can easily use my local SSMS to connect `ServerR`'s database engine and Reporting Service.

When I try to use my local Reporting Service Configuration Manager, even though I input Server Name as `ServerR` and click "Find", it shows "**No report servers were found.**"

Why?

Comment: You may need to right click and choose run as administrator when you run your local SSRS Conf manager in order to see them....

Comment: Hi Rvsc48, 
Thank you for your quick reply. I tried your way but still get the same error message. Any other consideration?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using a different version of Reporting Service Configuration Manager, then it wont pick it up.

SSRS Config Manager 2016 doesn't see my local SSRS 2012 instance and vice-versa.
Hope that helps.

Comment: You are so great! I tested it. Thanks a lot!